Duplicate Icons on Google Maps Controls in Blazor .NET8 App After Page Navigation
Issue with Duplicating Icons on Google Maps Buttons in Blazor .NET8 Application
I'm encountering a recurring issue in my Blazor .NET8 application where the buttons on my Google Maps (such as the zoom and fullscreen buttons) display repeated icons every time I navigate away from the map page and then return to it. Initially, when the map loads for the first time, everything appears normal. However, upon returning to the map after visiting other parts of the application, the icons on the map controls multiply.
Desired Behavior
I want the icons on the Google Maps buttons to remain singular and not duplicate when navigating away from and back to the map page.
Specific Problem
Each time I navigate back to the map page, the icons on the map controls (zoom, fullscreen, etc.) duplicate.
Code Example
Here is a simplified version of my code to illustrate the problem:
@page "/map"

@* MapContainer.razor *@
<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>

@code {
    private IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeMap");
        }
    }
}
@* JavaScript code *@
<script>
    let map;

    function initializeMap() {
        if (!map) {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
    }

    function cleanupMap() {
        if (map) {
            google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(map);
            map = null;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanupMap);
</script>

Request for Help
Could anyone suggest why this might be happening and how to fix this issue or properly clean up or reset the Google Maps instance to prevent icons from duplicating on the controls? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!
Steps Taken

Ensuring that the Google Maps API script is loaded only once.
Cleaning up the map instance using JavaScript before reinitializing the map.
Removing all markers, event listeners, and resetting the map variable to null.


You are cleaning the map only on window unload, which is event that happens when user navigates out of your web app (or closes the window)... So you are not calling the unload method when you move away from the /map page to /someOther page.
You can implement IDisposable and call the clean method there..
@implements IDisposable

...

@code {
    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
      await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("cleanupMap");
    }

Solution 2: Create unique id for every instance of map container.
string uniqueId = $"map-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[..8]}";

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeMap", uniqueId);
        }
    }

<script>
    let map;

    function initializeMap(uniqueId) {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(uniqueId), {
                center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                zoom: 8
            });
    }



Hi Alamakanambra, thank you for your answer. I've checked this approach but it looks that it is not possible to run JS in Dispose() method. I've received this error: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.)'. BTW the component is rendered using  InteractiveAuto.

I see... So it is more complex problem.. The issue we are facing is the fact that it goes through the init process even if the map is already there -> that's probably because you removed the div with id="map" and it somehow de-init the map (??) but kept the icons. Another option is to make a different id every time you create new map (access the page.) - see the updated answer.
